# Array.find returns TypeError / right use of params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routeparams

I want to access `name` from the data array but keep getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'. Can someone spot the mistake? `<button>{itemName}</button>` displays the name, but I can't access it with props...

```
export default function Home({ match }) {

  const item = data.find(item => item.name === match.params.itemName);

  return (
     <div>
      <button>{item.name.toUpperCase()}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export const data = [
  {
    name: "Apple",
    id: 1 
  },
  {
    name: "Banana",
    id: 2 
  },
  {
    name: "Blueberry",
    id: 3 
  }
];
```

Comment: `data.find(item => item.name === match.params.itemName)` this may return undefined

Answer (score 3):

You're just going to want to handle cases where there is no match or possibly invalid data.

```
export default function Home({ match }) {

const item = data
  .filter(item => item && item.name) // only items that have a name
  .find(item => item.name === match.params.itemName);

return item ? (
  <div>
    <button>{item.name.toUpperCase()}</button>
  </div>
) : (
  <div>
    Item not found.
  </div>
);
```

}